# Swiper.js CDN file renamed and breaking changes

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I was referencing the CDN version of [swiper.min.js](https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.0.0/js/swiper.min.js) and it appears that file went away or was renamed to [swiper-bundle.js](https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.0.0/swiper-bundle.js) on 7/3.

`Cannot find "/js/swiper.min.js" in swiper@6.0.0`

I downloaded and referenced a local copy of swiper-bundle.js, but something must have changed which broke my original code.

Anyone in the same situation and/or have a copy of the old version?

Comment: I had a similar experience. My references broke and then, when I updated to the "bundle" URLs, Swiper would no longer initialize. I followed your advice and switched to local copies of v5.4.5. Also, [this cdnjs link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Swiper) is now broken. Might be related: [Swiper 6.X #3671](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3671).

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but I think the copy of /js/swiper.min.js I was referencing at v6.0.0 was actually a hangover from the v5.4.5 build but the file didn't get cleaned up/removed until v6 was finalized on 07/03/2020.

I was able to go back to [v5.4.5](https://unpkg.com/browse/swiper@5.4.5/) and pull down local copies of the files I'd previously referenced and use those instead. I could have referenced the v5.4.5 versions via the CDN, but wanted to err on the side of caution after this scare.